# Keeping Partitions when formatting a hard drive

Tags: windows

Will doing a fresh install of windows 8 format all of the partitions on the drive or can i save particular partitions i do not wish to be touched during formatting procedure

Answer (score 0):

The installation process will only install on the drive and partition you choose.  In addition to that, it will not format a drive unless you select it in the Advanced options, or if the drive is unformatted, or an unrecognized filesystem.  If you have an existing Windows directory, it will be renamed.